# How to get all the issues found by code analyzers in roslyn?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I'm using a new roslyn's Code Analyzer feature. I have a ruleset with only one rule [CA1008](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/blob/master/src/AnalyzerPowerPack/AnalyzerPowerPack.md#ca1008-enums-should-have-zero-value): `Enums should have zero value.`. This rule is from `Microsoft.AnalyzerPowerPack` analyzer.

When I run Code Analysis in visual studio, it claims that

> Warning   CA0064  CA0064 : No analysis was performed because the specified rule set could not be loaded or did not contain any managed code analysis rules.

When I open some file, the warning normally pops up into the error window. How can I enforce VS to give me the results for all the files within the project, not just the opened ones?

Comment: You now have *two* code analyzers, VS2015 keeps on giving.  One that runs when you build your app, the Roslyn one, another that runs when you use the menu.  So you probably just want to rebuild your project.

Comment: You're sure you have selected 'Entire Solution' instead of 'Opened Documents' in the Error List window?

Comment: See [How to: Enable and Disable Full Solution Analysis for Managed Code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt709421.aspx)